# Is it possible to connect desktop/laptop display with smartphone?

Tags: applications, usb, screen

I have android smartphone . I have computer with Windows 7 operating system.

I want to see data that I am surfing on internet in my smartphone on my computer. If I connect my smartphone with my computer using USB cable, can I see content which is displayed on my smartphone's display (say any website) on desktop screen? Is it really possible to do it? Is there any apk available for it?  I don't want to root my smartphone.

Answer (score 2):

There is no native way to do this through through a USB port, although you have a few other options:

## 1. Use Mirror Beta

On your PC/Mac, download the [AllCast Receiver](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allcast-receiver/hjbljnpdahefgnopeohlaeohgkiidnoe) app for Chrome and launch it. On your Android phone download the [Mirror Beta](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.koushikdutta.mirror&referrer=utm_source%3D42matters.com%26utm_medium%3DWidgetWeb) app and make sure both devices are on the same Wi-Fi network. If everything works well, you should be able to see your Chrome browser as an option on your phone, tap that and it should work.

This doesn't require root, but it does need lollipop

## 2. Simply use an HDMI cable

Get a microUSB to HDMI converter, plug one end in the phone and the other end in your monitor or TV. It should work out of the box as an input in your TV. This method will have less lag and will work on older phones, but is less like what you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

If you enable USB debugging, you can actually use the [Chrome debugging tools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging) to view your smartphone's display for any website.

1. Enable USB debugging (under Developer Tools).

   [image: dev tools]

if Developer Tools isn't available in Settings, you may need to do the above.

2. Open the desired website in Google Chrome on your phone
3. Connect your phone to your computer via a microusb cable
4. In Google Chrome on your computer, navigate to Settings->More Tools->Inspect Devices
5. Check **Discover USB Devices**

[image: discover usb devices]
<sub>(source: [chrome.com](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging/chrome-discover-usb.png))</sub>

5. Allow USB debugging on your phone

[image: enable usb debugging]
<sub>(source: [chrome.com](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging/rsa-fingerprint.png))</sub>

6. At this point, you should be able to Inspect any webpages open on your phone from your computer

[image: inspect]
<sub>(source: [chrome.com](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging/chrome-inspect-tabs.png))</sub>

7. Tapping on the mobile icon in the Inspector should mirror your mobile display

[image: mobile icon]

the resulting display should look something like this:

[image: display]

**Note:** this solution will only mirror webpages, not other content.